# Merge Sort returning all zeroes

Tags: c#, mergesort

The output of the final merge is [0,0,0,0]. I think it's working right for the first merge of the left half of the array because it puts in order correctly. I would like help debugging this.

```
static public void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] input = { 4, 1, 3, 2};
    MergeSort(input, 0, input.Length - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input[i]);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static public void MergeSort(int[] input, int left, int right)
{
    if (left < right)
    { 
        int middle = (left + right) / 2;
        MergeSort(input, left, middle);
        MergeSort(input, middle + 1, right);
        Merge(input, left, (middle + 1), right);
    }
}

static public void Merge(int[] input, int left, int middle, int right)
{
    int tempindex = left;
    int[] tmp = new int[input.Length];
    int rightpointer = middle + 1;
    int leftpointer = left; 
    while (leftpointer <= middle && rightpointer <= right)
    {
        if (input[leftpointer] < input[rightpointer])
        {
            tmp[tempindex] = input[leftpointer];
            leftpointer++; 
        }
        else
        {
            tmp[tempindex] = input[rightpointer];
            rightpointer++;
        }
        tempindex++; 
    }
    while (leftpointer <= middle)
    {
        tmp[tempindex] = input[leftpointer];
        leftpointer++; 
        tempindex++;
    }
    while (rightpointer <= right)
    {
        tmp[tempindex] = input[rightpointer];
        right++;
        tempindex++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
    {
        input[i] = tmp[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you see when you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Hint: `for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)` - somethings wrong here.

Comment: There are many online resources to help you, with most of them providing a decent enough explanation on how its done. Some examples: [MergeSort.cs](https://gist.github.com/pmgeorg/9122984), [Merge Sorting Algorithm in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/merge-sorting-algorithm-in-c-sharp1) and [C# - Sorting Algorithm - Merge Sort Recursive](http://www.softwareandfinance.com/CSharp/MergeSort_Recursive.html)

Comment: Honestly my brain is so frazzled atm I can't seem to find it. Tried changing it to  for (int i = left; i < right; i++) and its not printing zeroes anymore. My brain just does not feel like cooperating right now lol

Answer (score 1):

Changed code slightly to make it work .  Please refer some online resources for better understanding of the algorithm

```
private static void Merge(int[] input, int left, int middle, int right)
    {
        int[] temp = new int[input.Length];
        int rightpointer = middle - 1;
        int tempindex = left;
        int num = right - left + 1;

        while ((left <= rightpointer) && (middle <= right))
        {
            if (input[left] <= input[middle])
            {
                temp[tempindex] = input[left];
                tempindex++;
                left++;
            }
            else
            {
                temp[tempindex] = input[middle];
                tempindex++;
                middle++;
            }
        }

        while (left <= rightpointer)
        {
            temp[tempindex] = input[left];
            tempindex++;
            left++;
        }

        while (middle <= right)
        {
            temp[tempindex] = input[middle];
            tempindex++;
            middle++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            input[right] = temp[right];
            right--;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than simply post a fixed version of your code, which I feel is a pointless and unhelpful exercise and would not benefit you in any important way, I will try to explain your mistakes from a higher-level point of view, with some advice on how to avoid similar mistakes in the future.

Your code has several problems in it. They fall into three categories:

1. Off-by-one. Classic programming error, something you should always be alert for any time you are dealing with indexes, and especially when dealing with the boundary values for those edge cases.
2. Simple typo. Another classic programming error. In this case, it's likely it happened when you copied and pasted a `while` loop, and then over-typed the wrong variable name. You should try to avoid copy/paste as much as possible; in the case of the classic merge sort, it's practically unavoidable, so you should follow the corollary rule: if you are copy/pasting where you have to change variable names in the pasted code, double- and triple-check your work!
3. Conceptual. This is "classic" in the sense that it's hard for programmers to learn good high-level conceptualization and abstraction skills, but it manifests itself in lots of different ways (unlike the first two), and so it's harder to provide general advice for. My best advice here is something a professor of mine years ago was fond of saying: KISS, or "[keep it simple, stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)." Or the way I like to express the same thing: "lazy is good". Either way, the point is to put your effort into simplifying the problem as much as possible. Keep your data modeling close to how you'd want to solve the problem if you had to do it by hand, and make sure if you had to do it by hand, you'd do it in the easiest, least labor-intensive way.

So, where did those mistakes show up? From last to first…

Conceptually, the biggest issue in your code is that your `Merge()` method allocates an array that is the full size of the `input` array, even though you *know* for sure the method is supposed to consider only a subset of that array. (You know that, because that's the whole point of the other three parameters to the method.)

This caused a problem later in the method, because when you went to copy the `tmp` array back to `input`, you just blindly wrote a loop to copy *all* of the data. This is even though the method has only actually written values to a subset of the `tmp` array. This, ultimately, is why your output is all zeroes. Not all of the values in the `tmp` array have been written, so they still have their default value of `0`, and then you copy those values into the `input` array, overwriting the original values you actually wanted.

Had you allocated for `tmp` an array only just large enough to contain the data you were actually going to manipulate during that particular call, it would have been painfully clear how to copy the data back at the end. Worst-case scenario, you would have gotten an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, which is a *much* nicer way to discover a bug than to just get the wrong output at the end (this is an example of the [Fail-fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) principle, another concept I'm fond of).

Now, about that typo. Frankly, that error you would have found eventually, once you had data that triggered it. As it happens, your input data set doesn't, because it never enters the loop where the bug was. But, your last `while` loop in the `Merge()` method is incrementing the `right` variable instead of the `rightindex` variable. This would lead to an `IndexOutOfRangeException` once the `tempindex` variable gets too large (so, at least it would have failed-fast :) ).

FWIW, in addition to simply making sure you double- and triple-check your work when you copy/paste, this is IMHO an example of why in simple loops like this, it's actually desirable to use the more concise syntax of putting the post-increment expression inside your array. Doing this ensures that the index you're incrementing is for sure the index you're using to index the array:

```
while (rightpointer <= right)
{
    tmp[tempindex++] = input[rightpointer++];
}
```

Finally, as for your off-by-one error, this is avoidable not just by being very careful when dealing with boundary values for indexes, but also by always keeping in mind some mental representation (I like to visualize the data structures) of how the values relate.

In this particular case, the value you pass for the `middle` parameter of the `Merge()` method is handled inconsistently. That is, in the `MergeSort()` method, the `middle` value is clearly used as the upper bound of the "left" side partition. This can be seen in the recursive calls to the `MergeSort()` method. But then when you call `Merge()`, you add one to the value for that call's `middle` parameter.

Yet, in the `Merge()` method, you are still using the parameter to indicate the upper bound of the left partition. When you pass `middle + 1` as that value, you are telling the `Merge()` method to treat a different section of the array as the left partition than the section that you actually sorted in the recursive call to `MergeSort()` before calling `Merge()`. This has obvious, and harmful, consequences in the outcome of the algorithm. :)

If you work harder to visualize those partitions, and the relationships of the variables that define them to the partitions, you would be less likely to write the wrong code in the first place.

Here is a corrected version of your code, with commented lines showing the changes I made:

```
static public void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] input = { 4, 1, 3, 2 };
    MergeSort(input, 0, input.Length - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input[i]);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static public void MergeSort(int[] input, int left, int right)
{
    if (left < right)
    {
        int middle = (left + right) / 2;
        MergeSort(input, left, middle);
        MergeSort(input, middle + 1, right);

        // was: Merge(input, left, (middle + 1), right);
        Merge(input, left, middle, right);
    }
}

static public void Merge(int[] input, int left, int middle, int right)
{
    // was: int tempindex = left;
    int tempindex = 0;

    // was: int[] tmp = new int[input.Length];
    int[] tmp = new int[right - left + 1];

    int rightpointer = middle + 1;
    int leftpointer = left;
    while (leftpointer <= middle && rightpointer <= right)
    {
        if (input[leftpointer] < input[rightpointer])
        {
            tmp[tempindex] = input[leftpointer];
            leftpointer++;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp[tempindex] = input[rightpointer];
            rightpointer++;
        }
        tempindex++;
    }
    while (leftpointer <= middle)
    {
        tmp[tempindex] = input[leftpointer];
        leftpointer++;
        tempindex++;
    }
    while (rightpointer <= right)
    {
        tmp[tempindex] = input[rightpointer];

        // was: right++;
        rightpointer++;

        tempindex++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
    {
        // was: input[i] = tmp[i];
        input[left + i] = tmp[i];
    }
}
```

Finally, I have not written anything about debugging. But really, the first step in trying to fix code is to step through it with a debugger. When you wrote the code, you had in mind various actions and outcomes that you expected the code to take. When you debug the code, what you're looking for is any place those expectations are violated.

Had you stepped through the code, one of the first things you would have found that violated your expectations was the copying of the uninitialized `0` values from the `tmp` array into the `input` array. You may or may not have fixed that particular problem the same way I did — the most expedient way at that point would in fact have been simply to change the boundaries of the `for` loop, to copy only those elements you actually wrote values to (I fixed it the way I did both because that uses less memory, and because it's an example of writing the code so that when there are mistakes, it can fail faster) — but at least you would have found the problem.